# Difference between Date.prototype.newFunction and Date.newFunction?

Tags: javascript

What would the difference be between Date.prototype.newFunction and Date.newFunction? I'm aware of how prototypal inheritance works in Javascript so I understand the prototype example, but the Date.newFunction throws me.

Comment: What are Date.prototype.newFunction and Date.newFunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I think you know, the prototype contains properties that will be automatically inherited by objects created via the constructor.

`Date.newFunction` is just a property on the constructor itself and it can only be accessed via `Date.newFunction`.  It is not inherited by objects created via the constructor and is not accessible via a particular instance created by the constructor.

Some would say that `Date.newFunction` is analogous to a class static method in other languages.  It's not a method attached to a particular instance, but more like a helper function for that object type.  These types of methods typically do not operate on instance data and they could just as easily be global utility functions, but it is often cleaner from a namespace point-of-view to assign them as properties of the constructor.

For example, on the Javascript `Date` object, methods such as `Date.now()` and `Date.parse()` are examples of this type of static methods.  You don't create an instance to use them, you just call them directly:

```
var tStart = Date.now();
```

---

One thing to remember is that any function in Javascript is an object too, so it can have arbitrary properties beyond just the `.prototype` property and using that capability for static methods is just one use.

Comment: @CharlesSounder - since it appears you may be fairly new to StackOverflow, are you aware of the green checkmark to the left of an answer.  When you get one or more answers that answer your question, you can select the best answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of an answer?  If you check it, it tells the community which answer you thought was best and indicates to the community that your question is now answered.  It also earns both you and the answerer some reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.a = function () {
    return 'Date.a';
};

Date.prototype.a = function () {
    return 'Date.prototype.a';
};

Date.a(); // return 'Date.a'
var b = new Date();
b.a(); // return 'Date.prototype.a'
```

Comment: clever ... but not sure it really answers the question with enough context.